# Getting segmentation fault in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Using this code for removing duplicate values which were created while processing the list start
but getting an error as segment failed when using this code, otherwise the program is running well.

```
void remove_duplicate(){
    q = start;           //list start has already been created
    while(q->next){
        q=q->next;
        if(q->id==q->next->id){    //removing duplicate values
            q->next->prev = q->prev;
            q->prev->next = q->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may lie in this line, here you assert that `q->next` element is present:

```
while(q->next)
```

Now you assign the next element in the chain to your q,

```
q=q->next;
```

Now your `q->next` may be `NULL`:

```
if(q->id==q->next->id)
```

Move you `q=q->next;` under `if` block.

```
void remove_duplicate(){

  q = start->next;    
  if (q==NULL)
  return -1;      
  while(q->next){

    if(q->id==q->next->id){                
        q->next->prev = q->prev;
        q->prev->next = q->next;
    }
    q=q->next;
  }
}
```

Comment: while(q->next) does exactly that. And your fix will crash right at the start as q->prev is probably NULL and you want to access it

Comment: probably NULL..., i don't now how this structure defined, my fix solve this particular problem with jumping on one node ahead

Comment: I misread your solution. the first sentence of my comment is not correct, the second still stands as it is.

Comment: But still opens up the problem with looking back. You just put the problem from the end the beginning. The analysis was right(i just misunderstood it the first time) but the problem was not solved.

Answer (score 2):

When you're are the second to last node in the list, where `q->next->next` is a null pointer, then you enter the loop body (because `q->next` is not `NULL`) and directly make `q` point to the last node. So when you next use `q->next` you will dereference a `NULL` pointer and have *undefined behavior*.

Change the order of your statements, and put the `q = q->next` assignment last.

Or use a `for` loop instead:

```
for (q = start; q->next != NULL; q = q->next){
    if ...
}
```

Comment: @ÐevendraSuthar You might mark the answer that helped you out as accepted. This is better than a thanks because everyone sees that this is the solution + the poster gets rep for his work.

Answer (score 0):

```
void remove duplicate()
{
   q=start;

   while(q->next!=NULL)
   {
      if(q->id==q->next->id)
      {
         q->next=q->next->next; 
      }

      q=q->next;
   }
}
```

It could help you.

Comment: Also your answer would be much better if you would have explained why it could help, what was the problem originally.

Comment: here q is a pointer .in this case we start traversing of element with condition (q->next!=NULL) .on this condition we can find the duplicate value of prev node .In the prev code while loop is not perfectly defined from where our loop would terminate and in prev code if condition is right but inside the if loop ,

Comment: the pointer q is pointing a node and in if condition we are comparing the next node's id and if that is matched then in the q->next holding the address of next node(duplicate node) and next of duplicate node holding the address of third node then the step (q->next=q->next->next) is defining , in the next of pointing node at this time put the address of third node and break the connection between the duplicate node and pointing node at this time.

Comment: You can edit your answer and add this information instead posting it in comments.